# Mule#4: RAML not able to parse JSON in escape characters

Tags: bad-request, mule4, raml

I have following schema declared in RAML 1.0

```
body:
   application/json:
    type: object
                properties:
                  region:
                    example:
                      strict: false
                      value: NA
                    type: string
                    required: true
                  country:
                    description: Country name
                    example:
                      strict: false
                      value: US
                    type: string
                    required: true
                  orders:
                    type: array
                    items:
                      properties:
                        orderName:
                          example:
                            strict: false
                            value: "toys"
                          type: string
                          maxLength: 20
                          required: false
                        orderNumber:
                          example:
                            strict: false
                            value: order12
                          type: string
                          maxLength: 25
                          required: false
                    maxItems: 100
                    required: true
```

When I am sending the below JSON request

```
{
    "region": "South America",
    "country": "US",
    "orders": [
        "{\n  \"orderNumber\": \"ORD0118\",\n  \"orderName\": \"toys\"\n}",
        "{\n  \"orderNumber\": \"ORD0119\",\n  \"orderName\": \"pens\"\n}",
        "{\n  \"orderNumber\": \"ORD0120\",\n  \"orderName\": \"pencils\"\n}"
    ]
}
```

In batch when I am aggregating message and concatenating the payload, the payload was getting formatted as above.
I am seeing a bad request error

```
Position: Line 0,  Column 0\n/orders/0 expected type: JSONObject, found: String  Location:   Position: Line 0,  Column 0\n/orders/1 expected type: JSONObject, found: String  Location:   Position: Line 0,  Column 0\n/orders/2 expected type: JSONObject, found: String  Location:   Position: Line 0,  Column 0",
```

Please help me in updating RAML to accept the JSON in escape characters as well.

Answer (score 1):

The payload's orders attribute is a list of strings, not of objects, because the members of the array are 'escaped'. Depending on what you intend to do, you can change the RAML to set the array to an array of strings, or convert somehow the strings to the objects the RAML expects.

For the former replace the definition of orders by something like:

```
           orders:
                type: string[]
```

If you want to do the later the following DataWeave script will transform the list in the expected objects:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    region: payload.region,
    country: payload.country,
    orders: payload.orders map read($,"application/json")
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "region": "South America",
  "country": "US",
  "orders": [
    {
      "orderNumber": "ORD0118",
      "orderName": "toys"
    },
    {
      "orderNumber": "ORD0119",
      "orderName": "pens"
    },
    {
      "orderNumber": "ORD0120",
      "orderName": "pencils"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response.I tried the approach to parse it using read function before calling API. For some reason the it was going still in escaping characters.
The second approach to update the RAML specs and do the parsing in receiving application is not a standard approach in our project.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the preserve MIME types in batch aggregator solved this issue.